# Redux page breaks in Android WebView in Kitkat

Tags: android, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am rendering my Redux app like so -

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <MyComponent />
</Provider>
```

the compiled code is

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
    _reactRedux.Provider,
    { store: store },
    React.createElement(MyComponent, null)
), document.getElementById(element_id));
```

This throws the error `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child.` The development version of React also throws the following warning `Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop 'children' supplied to 'Provider', expected a single ReactElement.`

If I change it to simply

```
<div>"Content"</div>
```

the compiled code comes out as

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    '"Content"'
), document.getElementById(element_id));
```

and it renders properly.

The Provider version loads fine in desktop chrome as well as the chrome browser on the device.

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you sure `MyComponent` is correctly imported/defined ? If so, does its `render` method return a valid React element ?

Comment: What `MyComponent` renders to shouldn’t matter here though.

Comment: Exactly as Dan mentioned. `MyComponent` renders properly in the mobile browser (on same device) as well as desktop. Zero code changes.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do something with babel polyfill. If i remove the polyfill from the build process and use a CDN like polyfill.io using the tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Then the problem is fixed and webpage loads. Still have to figure out why this happens though.